# Is $C[a,b]$ with $p$-norm a normed vectorspace?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

For $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, consider the set $C([a,b]):=\{f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: $f$ \text{ is continuous} \}$. Define $||f||_p:=\biggl(\int_a^b |f(x)|^p dx\biggr)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

a) Is $C([a,b])$ a vector space (over $\mathbb{R} ,\mathbb{C}$)?

b) Is $(C([a,b]),||\cdot||_p)$ a normed vector space?

What I did:

Regarding a)

By pointwise evaluation, it is easy to see that $C([a,b])$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $\mathbb{C}$, in the complex case one just has to split everything into real and imaginary parts.

Regarding b)

For $||\cdot||_p$ to be a norm we have to show that $||f||_p=0 \Rightarrow f=0$.

Since $f$ is continuous, we can define $g(x):=|f(x)|^p$ which is also continuous. the fundamental theorem of calculus ensures us that $g$ has an antiderivative
$G(x):= \int_a^x g(t) dt$.

But since $g(x) \geq 0$, the function $G$ is monotonically increasing. Hence, $G(a) \leq G(b)$. But this implies that $\int_a^b g(x) dx =G(b) - G(a) \geq 0$.

If now $\int_a^b g(x) dx=0$, this implies that G(b)-G(a)=0

Because $G$ is monotonically increasing, $G$ has to be constant. Thus its derivative is 0, i.e. $g=0$.

Further $|| \lambda f ||_p= |\lambda| ||f||_p$.
And by the Minkowski inequality we see that $||f+g||_p \leq ||f||_p+||g||_p$.

So my answer is, that $(C[a,b], ||\cdot||)$ is a normed vector space.
Is this correct?

Comment: There is no natural way to make the space of real-valued functions on an interval into a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$. I think you have got that part of (a) wrong. Your proof of (b) looks good. Another proof of (b) goes like this: if $g(t) \neq 0$, then, by continuity, $g(x)$ is bounded below by some $\delta > 0$ in an interval containing $t$ of length $\epsilon > 0$ say and then $\|f\|_p = \int_a^b g(x)d(x) > \delta\epsilon$.

Comment: @RobArthan So it is because the definition says $f :[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then if $\lambda = i$, $i \cdot f \notin C([a,b])$, right? Would it work if one changes the condition to $f :[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, $C([a. b])$ wouldn't be closed under scalar multiplication under the natural way of trying to make it into a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$. If you change $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{C}$ in the definition of $C([a, b])$, then you do get a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ and the proof of part (b) goes through to show that it is a normed vector space.

Comment: @RobArthan thank you